# How to declare priority queue in function parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, priority-queue

I have declare a priority queue for with minimum element at the top as follows

```html
priority_queue<int, vector<int> , greater<vector<int>> > low;
```

Now I want to pass this object to some function, for this i need to declare in function header, I tried declaring following ways

```html
int fun1(priority_queue<int, vector<int> , greater<vector<int>> > min_heap){
return 0;
}
```

```html
int fun2(priority_queue<int> min_heap){
return 0;
}
```

in both approach i am getting compilation error;
second approach is obvious to give error because of type mismatch but compiler does not allow to do first approach.
Please help me.

Comment: _in both approach i am getting compilation error_ And, you didn't copy-paste the error messages, because? They should state, exactly, what's wrong. In addition - please provide [mcve].

Comment: Do you actually intend to make a duplicate copy of the priority queue, in order to pass it to your function by value? If not, you need to open the chapter in your C++ book that explains how to use references, and read it.

Comment: The last template parameter is used to compare elements of the queue (in your case, `int`s), not containers used to store those elements (that is, not `vector<int>`s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the compiler error, but I'm going to try to guess your problem even without it.

Your declaration is probably wrong, that is, your:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int> , greater<vector<int>> > low;
```

**should be instead**:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int> , greater<int> > low;
```

Note the third template parameter.

Since you have a `queue` of `int` the *comparator* has to be defined over, indeed, `int` and not on `std::vector<int>`.

In that way should compiler.
[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/zEUzJx) an example.